# How to use HTML to print header and footer on pdf use of jspdf

Tags: jspdf

In my HTML page, 2 diff chart is available that's the way I convert full page as an image and after it saves as pdf using jspdf.
I need set header or footer before it update in html2Canvas and jspdf.
but how can I add header and footer in pdf?

Answer (score 1):

You don't add headers and footers in PDF. Read more about [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF), it is a low level standardized format, where the primitive operations are something like *move to coordinate x=340, y=450* (in some unit, perhaps tenth of millimeters or typographical points) and *change font to Helvetica 10* and *show the `a` letter*. Read the [PDF standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/63534.html).

You may generate PDF from some higher level text format. I recommend reading about [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) and [Lout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_(software)) and many other such document processors. You could consider generating some LaTeX or Lout file, then converting it to PDF (by running some `pdflatex` or `lout` [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))).

You could use a PDF generating library such as [JagPDF](http://www.jagpdf.org/) and many others.

You might find HTML to PDF converters. Most web browsers have one. Look also into [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).